# How to call a Logic App from Azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to call a Logic app that I created, from Azure Data Factory using the WebHook component and its returning an error of Bad Request , I am not sure what is wrong . I am using the Post method and copying in the body the same json body that I have defined in the HTTP request in the Logic App.

Thank you,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked for me Instead of `Webhook` I have used `Web` and included the logic apps URL to my data factory Web.

Here is the sample that I followed, Firstly I have taken 2 variables

1. ListOfFiles of dataType Array
2. strListOfFiles of dataType string

Here is the pipeline that I'm using:

[image]

**`ForEach`**  loop Activities:

[image]

I have made items in my settings to read the child items i.e..

```
@activity('Get List of Files').output.childitems
```

Then in the  **`set variables`**  I'm storing all the arrays of  `ListOfFiles`  inside  `strListOfFiles`

[image]

And then in the  **`Web`**  Im using my Logic App URL making post method having  `{ "ListOfFiles":@{variables('strListOfFiles')} }`  inside the body.

[image]

**Logic App workflow**

[image]

Im using the below JSON Schema inside the HTTP request

```
{
    "properties": {
        "ListOfFiles": {
            "type": "array"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Webhook in Azure Data Factory is waiting for an immediate response (within 1 minute) to confirm receiving the trigger. To do this inside Logic App you need to create a response action with Status 202 and put it right after the HTTP trigger.

To pass the results/resulting status from the Logic App to the Data Factory, you need to put at the end a HTTP action to call ADF's callback URL that is sent in the trigger body (using expression `triggerBody()['callBackUri']`).

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "method": "POST",
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        },
        "actions": {
            "Response_Accepted": {
                "inputs": {
                    "statusCode": 202
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "operationOptions": "Asynchronous",
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Response"
            },
            ......,
            "HTTP_callback": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {},
                    "method": "POST",
                    "uri": "@{triggerBody()['callBackUri']}"
                },
                "runAfter": {<the last action doing something>},
                "type": "Http"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: 202response]

[image: callback]