# how can we pass the output of a sql query into a REST endpoint body in Azure Data Factory copy activity?

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

We are using azure data factory copy activity to query (select * from table a for json path ) data from on-prem SQL server

We want to pass on the response of this query to a logic app - which will then parse this json array to individual records and push it into Event hubs

We are not publishing directly to Event hubs because of 1 MB message limit per message

How can we pass on this json array to logic app in proper manner ( given it adds some slashes in between the data when we pass it to logic app)

Please suggest

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70173161/how-to-call-a-logic-app-from-azure-data-factory

Comment: further reading can also be found here https://davidalzamendi.com/executing-azure-logic-apps/

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just handle the extra slashes once you have the data in the logic app? Can you provide any example of what your current configuration and data looks like and why it isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can we pass on this json array to logic app in proper manner ( given it adds some slashes in between the data when we pass it to logic app)

To manage extra slashes, make sure you are passing correct and using correct body schema for logic app.

Here mis my lookup output which fetching Json from SQL query.
[image]

Then I used set variable to convert it into array without extra slashes using dynamic functions.

**Expression I used:**

```
@json(replace(substring(split(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value),'00805F49916B')[1],3,lastindexof(split(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value),'00805F49916B')[1],'"')),'\',''))
```

here first I am converting output to string then splitting it using column name the taking substring to remove  `"` quotes from, starting and then replacing `\` with `''` and the again converting it to json.

[image]

**Converted in proper array format.**

[image]

Logic app body schema should be as follow:

[image]

Passing our array to web activity:

[image]

**In logic app I am getting proper array where I am fetching body value in array variable:**

[image]